# Local informatics Olympiad and Algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science, contest-math, recursive-algorithms

I see one of recent local informatics Olympiad question. i have a trouble to solve it. any idea? hint? or solutions? thanks to all creative man.

We have two function $P_1, P_2$ and input an array $n$ bit called $x$. $P_1$ calculate $y_1=A_1x$ and $P_2$ calculate $y_2=A_2x$. $A_1, A_2$ is $n*n$ bit matrix. the output of these two functions is $n$ bit array  $y_1, y_2$. we nothing know about these matrix but know  $A_1, A_2$ is the same except one slot $(I,J)$. we can call $P_1,P_2$ with different $x$'s and compare the output of these calls. with how many number of calls can find $I, J$ index?

Comment: May i suggest trying with a small $n$ and then scale up? This sounds awfully like those tedious weights problems (bank interviewers seem to like) which which can also be approached in a similar fashion..just maybe though :).

Comment: Dear @Chinny84, three days i though :) nothing....

Comment: What do you consider matrix multiplication with bits, are you using the XOR function to multiply bits $a$ and $b$? For instance: $$a \times b = a \oplus b = \begin{cases}1 & \text{if } a = 1 \text{ and } b = 1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Dear @Shaktal, I not consider that. this is a question in Olympiad some weeks ago.

Comment: @MounaMokhiab Did the Olympiad not specify how the elements of the array and the matrix were to be multiplied together then?

Comment: Dear @Shaktal, no i exact mentioned the question.

Comment: Dear @Shaktal, i believe,  this is not important. suppose we have a black box, input is x, and we can compare the result.

Comment: Thinking about it further you can easily get the column or row by comparing the outputs of the two functions..now for the other bit you can use ones and zeros in the $x$ Ie the first half of the array of x are zeros and the rest some other number this will find which half half of the row has the error and you can proceed as follows..though this could be completely wrong. Anyway that's my two pennies worth.

Comment: The statement says $x$ is "a array *n* bit" while $A_1,A_2$ are both $n\times n$ bit matrices.  However ordinary arithmetic will not give a matrix-vector product $A_1 x$ or $A_2 x$ that is necessarily $n$ "bit array" output.  Indeed taking $x$ to be the array of all ones, the products $A_1 x$ and $A_2 x$ will be the respective row sums of the matrices, if ordinary matrix multiplication is used.  So the nature of the matrix multiplication needs to be cleared up, but using the all-ones $x$ at least narrows down the row in which $A_1$ and $A_2$ disagree, whether real arithmetic or Boolean is used